# In rails, File name gets deleted in file field when reloading the page

Tags: filefield

In any rails form, when we are uploading a file, file name getting deleted when we left any mandatory field.

Also once we saved a file, again when try to edit the file file name is not display in edit form.
Please tell me solution for this issue. Actually we don't want to reset the file field after reloading the page.

Comment: File field where? You have to tell us if it's in HTML, javascript, some server-side framework?

Answer (score 1):

what uploader plugin / gem are you using? carrierwave has a great feature to support persistence of uploaded files while redisplaying the form because of failed validations, see "Making uploads work across form redisplays" at https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave